# NUnit3-Console.exe on Win Server 2012 has no TestFixtures

Tags: nunit-3.0

I have been running NUnit3-Console on Win 2012 for almost two years. I recently updated my tests to .Net 4.7.2 and updated the NUnit and Selenium to the latest versions. I have installed NUnit3-Console v3.8 on the server and .Net 4.7.2.

All of the tests that used to run fine now fail with the message "Has no TestFixtures.

I wrote a simple test to isolate the issue and it does the same thing.

My Base class

```
enter code here
using NUnit.Framework;
using Utilities;

namespace CommonCode2.TestBases
{
    public class NoSeleniumBase
    {

        public Parameters parms = new Parameters();

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void InitializePageTests()
        {
            parms.GetParameters();
        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void CleanupPageTests()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

My SimpleTest

```
enter code here
using CommonCode2.TestBases;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;

namespace SimpleTest
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass : NoSeleniumBase
    {
        [Test]
        public void Atest()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is a simple test");
        }
    }
}
```

The NUnit files are installed in C:\NUnit and the test is invoked using.

```
C:\Nunit\NUnit3-Console.exe --where "name =~ 'Atest'" 
"C:\QA_Libraries3\SimpleTest.dll"
```

The TestResult file contains this tag

```
<property name="_SKIPREASON" value="Has no TestFixtures" />
```

and a message block

```
<![CDATA[Has no TestFixtures]]></message>
```

I am hoping that someone has encountered this issue and can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Charlie Poole and Rob Prouse for their responsive and helpful support. The issue was not with NUnit3-Console but with the tests library directory access. Deleting and recreating the directory resolved the issue.